# Angular ngFor - get a property in ts

Tags: arrays, angular, chat, ngfor, string-interpolation

I need some help here please...

Im making a chat app with angular and material, and i need to show the user nickname only one time before the next user messages enter in action (like whatsapp or similar), something like this:

user1:
message 1
message 2
message 3
user2:
message 1
message 2
user1:
message 4
etc

This is my component.ts:

```
  messages: any[] = [
    {
      nickname: 'user1',
      msg: 'hola que tal 1',
      img: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81PohdE46lL.jpg"
    },
    {
      nickname: 'user1',
      msg: 'hola que tal 2',
      img: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81PohdE46lL.jpg"
    },
    {
      nickname: 'user1',
      msg: 'hola que tal 3',
      img: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81PohdE46lL.jpg"
    },
    {
      nickname: 'user2',
      msg: 'hola que tal 4',
      img: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81PohdE46lL.jpg"
    },
    {
      nickname: 'user2',
      msg: 'hola que tal 4',
      img: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81PohdE46lL.jpg"
    },
  ];

username: string = "test";
temp_user: string = "";

changeTemp(nickname: string): void {
    this.temp_user = nickname;
  }
```

And this is my HTML with the (ugly) solution im achieved:

```
            <mat-card-content>
                <div class="chat-window" #chat_window>
                    <mat-list role="list">
                        <div *ngFor="let msg of messages">
                            <div *ngIf="temp_user !== msg.nickname" class="avatar"
                                [ngClass]="{ 'right-avatar': msg.nickname == username}">
                                <!-- <img class="avatar-img" [src]="msg.img" alt="..."> -->
                                {{ msg.nickname }}
                                {{ changeTemp(msg.nickname) }}
                            </div>
                            <mat-list-item class="chat-message" role="listitem"
                                [ngClass]="{ 'right-message': msg.nickname == username}">
                                {{ msg.msg }}
                            </mat-list-item>
                        </div>
                    </mat-list>
                </div>
            </mat-card-content>
```

This is the result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5RvW.png)
I called the changeTemp() function with string interpolation to save temp user and check if its repeated before next user msg with an ngIf but this (call a function in this situation) not sounds like a good practice to me...

There is a clean way to solve this? get temp user in some way or an alternative? i have tried with a directive that emits an event, and a trackBy solution, but not worked fine in this situation.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can put this function to execute when the user sends a message (or receives), so it won't be necessary to execute this function with interpolation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your list in a more convenient order before you throw it to HTML to do its job.

Assume that your array is,

```
var arr = [
  {tag: 'one', content: 'A'},
  {tag: 'one', content: 'B'},
  {tag: 'two', content: 'C'},
  {tag: 'two', content: 'D'},
  {tag: 'three', content: 'E'},
  {tag: 'three', content: 'F'}
];
```

Convenient order would like,

```
{
      one: [
        {tag: 'one', content: 'A'},
        {tag: 'one', content: 'B'}
      ],
      two: [
        {tag: 'two', content: 'C'},
        {tag: 'two', content: 'D'}
      ],
      three: [
        {tag: 'three', content: 'E'},
        {tag: 'three', content: 'F'}
      ]
    }
```

you can group the array by using "group-array" package or manually. If you wish to use "group-array" package,  bellow I have mentioned the link and a example copied from original documentation to group the array.
Link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/group-array#examples

```
//npm i group-array
// group by the `tag` property
   groupArray(arr, 'tag');
```

In your HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of yourList | keyvalue">
   <div >
       Message From - {{item.key}}
   </div>
   <div>
       <p  *ngFor="let message of item.value">
            {{message.content}}
       </p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Output :

```
Message From - one
A
B

Message From - three
E
F

Message From - two
C
D
```

Comment: This not solve my specific problem but it is the response i needed, i have to focus on my data composition before the ngFor and not focus on how to treat the data inside the template and the ngFor (bad practice)... this group-array package is very useful also, thanks